# Rails A method with 2 returns - how to get them?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
parse_emails('long list')


def parse_emails(emails)
  .... stuff
  return valid_emails, invalid_emails
end
```

I see that there are two arrays but how do I get them? I tried:

```
mylist = parse_emails('long list')
mylist[valid_emails]
```

but that error'd. ideas? thxs

Comment: is that the right way to do it? Seems like that would be confusing later on

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`valid_emails, invalid_emails = parse_emails(whatever)`

Please take time to read some basic intro into Ruby syntax ;)

Comment: This sort of list-expansion comes from Perl and can be confusing to people not familiar with the nuances of list assignment. It is probably one of the least understood syntax elements.

Comment: This is called 'tuples'. Adding parens around them makes things more obvious: a single object, which contains two values inside, is returned and assigned to another such object with two receptacles inside. `(a, b) = foo()`

Comment: [] for either may just mean that you actually return two empty lists from a function. Consider this crude example: http://paste.org/pastebin/view/26304

Answer (score 1):

Construct an class with two lists in it, one for valid emails and one for invalid emails and populate the object of this class in parse_emails function and return it.

Then, in the outside, you can access those two lists as properties of the return value.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the two arrays into the method, then populate them in there:

```
invalid_emails = []
valid_emails = []
parse_emails('long list', valid_emails, invalid_emails)


def parse_emails(emails, valid, invalid)
  .... stuff
  while ...
    if is_valid?
      valid << current_email
    else 
      invalid << current_email
    end
  end
end
```